# Why can't I send data from service to activity?

Tags: android

This code in service I try to send data from service to activity but it does not work,

> ```
> public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
>
> // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>   super.onStart(intent, startId);
>   Toast.makeText(this, "onstart()",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>   String message = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
>   int ID = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
>   Toast.makeText(getApplication(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>   NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>
>   Intent notificationintent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
>
>   notificationintent.putExtra("ID", ID);
>
>   PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,ID, notificationintent,0);
>
>   int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
>   String tickerText = "you have a massege";
>   long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
>   Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
>
>   String contentTitle = "Title";
>   String contentText = message;
>   notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, pendingintent);
>   notification.defaults = notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
>
>   notificationmanager.notify(ID, notification);
> ```

This is activity

```
Intent i = new Intent();
int num = i.getExtras().getInt("ID");
number.setText(num); // number is textview
```

Comment: maybe not new intent but getIntent()

Comment: unless you're not showing something `i` doesn't have any extras at that point.

Comment: Please read @Vishal Pawale's code. There is your problem. And by the way. I think your code will crash because you are passing number in "setText" method on your view. It should be "number.setText(num+"");"

Answer (score 2):

Change your activity code like this -

```
  int num = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID", 0);

  number.setText(String.valueOf(num)); // number is textview
```

Comment: +1. He is creating NEW intent, instead getting already existed one.

Comment: What's the error?And in case of int, `TextView` takes `resourceId`, the resource id of String, `R.string.someString`

Comment: getIntent() will get the intent that started the activity, I could be wrong here, but I don't think the service started this activity, did it?

Comment: @nPn - Refer this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Comment: Then it that case, please post your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't this you can directly communicate from a service to an activity.  Remember a service may be running independent of any activity.  You can communicate from the activity to the service via startService calls, passing an intent.

In order to communicate back to an activity the activity must bind to the service:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

The other option is the service can send a broadcast and the activity can get a messages via a handler passed to the broadcast receiver.